Constant output voltage in buck-boost converters
I'm a self-taught student. I'm trying to understand the working principle of buck-boost converters in continuous conduction mode.
When the switch is turned on, the equation describing the inductor is the following:
$$ V_L = V_{in} = L \frac{d i_L}{dt} $$
I've tried to understand why the voltage across the inductor is constant. I think it is thanks to the generator to which the inductor is connected in parallel, and which provides constant voltage, so the first half of the waveform of the current flowing through the inductor is linear.
I don't understand the second half, when the switch is opened. I've seen many videos (such as this) and I've tried to read some articles, and in every one of them the equation describing the inductor is:
$$ V_L = -V_{out} = L\frac{di_L}{dt} $$
This is then solved by separation of variable, and this leads to the fact that the second half of the waveform is linear too. The justification for this seems obscure to me: how can one assume that the output voltage \$ V_{out} \$ needs to be constant?
The capacitor behaves differently: When the switch is on, the current flowing through the capacitor \$i_C = -i_{out}\$ because of the opposite directions, resulting in a linear decreasing waveform; when the switch is off, we have this:
$$ i_C = i_L - i_R $$
The current through the inductor is time-dependent, resulting in a waveform of the type \$ A - Ce^{-Bt} \$.
This raises another question: Why does the capacitor behave like this and the inductor in the other way? In other words: why one can assume the output voltage constant but not the output current?
Here is an image of the circuit for reference (from this source):


What is the source of that image of the circuit?

I've searched it on google images, it is the topology I'm working with

Look here, your P-channel MOSFET is reversed, unless you meant an N-channel, but the arrow must point in the other direction. The equations you shown assume a converter at steady-state - in regulation - so $V_{out}$ is assumed constant. Regarding the inductor current, we assume the time constant of the inductor (with its dc resistance) is very large compared to the switching period: the current ramps up or down linearly with a slope equal to $\frac{V}{L}$.

@Verbal Kint there was, in fact, an error: the transistor should be an N-MOS. I will change the reference image and cite the source, as requested!

I'd expect reverse polarity across the output. But that's a minor detail.

@Luke__ , I recommend you look at my recent seminar on power conversion, there is a section on the buck-boost converter with many illustrations.

yes, it should be reversed

V0 is reversed.  The output voltage across R is reversed with respect to Vi.  The circuit is an inverting boost converter.

Is it just me, or does the term "buck-boost" now have two meanings, BLT and ALT?  (Before Linear Technology, and After Linear Technology)  Their "buck-boost" controllers have a very different topology from a simple boost converter with a reversed output diode.

@Luke__, Do you understand that when a switch is closed it conducts and when it is open it doesn't? In electronics the terminology comes from the concept of a closed circle. Current always travels in a circle unless the circle is open.

yes I do, when the switch is opened, nonetheless, there are just the inductor, the capacitor and the load resitor: what guarantees me that the voltage across the load remains constant? That is, why must V_out maintain the same value? (Since V_out is factored out the integral it is treated as constant)


I've tried to understand why the voltage across the inductor is constant. I think it is thanks to the generator to which the inductor is connected in parallel, and which provides constant voltage, so the first half of the waveform of the current flowing through the inductor is linear.

Correct.
While the inductor current is increasing the output current is being supplied by the capacitor, downward through the capacitor and upward through the load. |Vout| decreases slowly during this time.
The diode is not conducting at this time.

I don't understand the second half, when the switch is opened.

The inductor current must travel in the same direction, but now is directed upward through the capacitor and the load. So he capacitor current reverses direction. The load current direction is the same, but now the load voltage magnitude is increasing.
The diode is conducting at this time.
Pretending for the moment that the diode voltage is zero, then \$V_L=-V_o\$.

how can one assume that the output voltage Vout
needs to be constant?

You are right. The output voltage is indeed an exponential, not a constant. So the capacitor is chosen to be large enough so that the deviation from the average (steady state) value is small. So a better relationship is \$V_L\approx V_{oAverage}\$.
This means that the decrease in \$I_L\$ is approximately linear. The \$CR_{\text{load}}\$ time constant must be very long relative to the switching period to make the approximation effective.
When the load changes, the approximation is no longer valid until a new average is steady.
In electronics you will find that approximations are sometimes used to help make problems more tractable within specific constraints.
